# ASP.Net Core, detecting debugging vs. not debugging in a controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am writing my first ASP.Net code web app and in my controller I would like to have an `if` statement that checks to see if I am in debugging mode or not. I know in the Startup.cs file I can check `env.IsDevelopment()` but that is because the `IHostingEnvironment` is passed into it. I have not been able to find a way to check for this status inside a normal controller. Is there a way in ASP.Net Core to detect when I am in debug mode inside the controller that I am missing?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Update**: @Pradeep Kumar's [post below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42776771/2525561) is the more correct answer here. This answer only indicates how to access the IsDevelopment() environment flag via dependency injection in a controller.

**Update**:
IHostingEnvironment is obsolete in .Net Core 3.1 see the following for .Net Core 3.1+
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61703339/2525561

You should be able to just inject IHostingEnvironment into your controller constructor.

```
protected readonly IHostingEnvironment HostingEnvironment;

public TestController(IConfiguration configuration, IHostingEnvironment hostingEnv){
    this.Configuration = configuration;
    this.HostingEnvironment = hostingEnv;
}

[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Test(){
    if(this.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment()){
        // Do something
    }

    return View();
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. I am new with Core and DI so this did not even cross my mind.

Comment: Wow, the lightbulb finally went on, DI is built in. It's still not clear to me how I'd have known that the hosting environment was available to be injected (I know, RTFM). Thank you for this straight forward example.

Comment: This only tells you environment.. if you have a development server that you deploy code to it will show true for that, but it is not a debugging environment which was the original question..

Answer (score 22):

`IHostingEnvironment` lets you know the environment in which the application is running. Looks like what you need is the build configuration used to build the application i.e Debug/Release. In an ASP.NET Core web application, In order to get this information at compile time, there is no straight forward way, however you can have a property with conditional compilation using compiler directives, something like

```
public static bool IsDebug
{
  get
     {
      bool isDebug = false;
    #if DEBUG
       isDebug = true;
    #endif
       return isDebug;
      }
}
```

At runtime, you can check the value of IsDebug property to determine the build configuration. I would suggest to add this property to a common static or utility class which can be accessible from all your controllers.

Comment: This is the correct methodology. thanks

Comment: Same as `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached`.

Answer (score 13):

It's not `IHostingEnvironment` nowadays, it's **`IWebHostEnvironment`**.
In ASP.NET Core 3.1, `IHostingEnvironment` causes a warning

```
CS0618  'IHostingEnvironment' is obsolete: 'This type is obsolete 
and will be removed in a future version. 
The recommended alternative is 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostEnvironment.'
```

Consequently, the accepted answer should be updated as follows:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;


public class TestController : Controller
{
    protected readonly IWebHostEnvironment HostEnvironment;

    public TestController(IWebHostEnvironment hostEnv) {
        this.HostEnvironment = hostEnv;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Test(){
        if (this.HostEnvironment.IsDevelopment()){
            // Do something
        }

        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me :)

Comment: Optimax's solution only tells you the environment. Not if it is being debugged.

Comment: @roblem Added an alternative answer.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to my own answer, prompted by the comment by user @roblem, and based on an alternative reading of the OP's question, is as follows:

### Managed Debuggers

To detect if a managed (.NET) debugger is *actually* attached to the process, one can use `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached` property. This is useful during development when you need to programmatically determine if your code is running from the IDE or standalone.

```
using System.Diagnostics;

if (Debugger.IsAttached)
{
    // Debugger is attached, we are probably running from the IDE
}
else
{
    // We are probably running standalone
}
```

Note that the above only works for managed debuggers, such as the one built into the IDE.

### Unmanaged Debuggers

To detect if an unmanaged debugger is attached, one needs to call `CheckRemoteDebuggerPresent` WinAPI function:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class DetectDebugger
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
    static extern bool CheckRemoteDebuggerPresent(IntPtr hProcess, ref bool isDebuggerAttached);

    public static void Main()
    {
        bool isDebuggerAttached = false;
        CheckRemoteDebuggerPresent(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle, ref isDebuggerAttached);

        Console.WriteLine("Debugger is attached: " + isDebuggerAttached);
        // Prevent the console window from immediately closing:
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

### Summary

In summary (found [here](https://codingvision.net/c-detect-if-debugger-is-attached)):

- `CheckRemoteDebuggerPresent` - works for any running process and detects native debuggers too.
- `Debugger.IsAttached` - works only for the current process and detects only managed debuggers. As an example, [OllyDbg](https://www.ollydbg.de/) won’t be detected by this.